# NGINX - WORDPRESS - PHP-FPM: Query parameters (GET) not passing in subfolders

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm, wordpress

I have a wordpress site running with NGINX (and Php-fpm) with 4 virtualhosts, everything works fine, except if i want to pass a query string.
Look, it works if i do:

```
example.com/phpfile.php?var=123
```

But it doesn't if i try

```
exaple.com/subfolder/subfolder2/phpfile.php?var=123
```

Here is my /nginx/snippets/wordpress.conf:

```
location = /favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
    try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
}

   
location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
}

# Deny access to any files with a .php extension in the uploads directory
# Works in sub-directory installs and also in multisite network
# Keep logging the requests to parse later (or to pass to firewall utilities such as fail2ban)
location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
    deny all;
}
# End Restrictions

# Caching
set $skip_cache 0;

# POST requests and urls with a query string should always go to PHP
if ($request_method = POST) {
        set $no_cache 1;
}
if ($query_string != "") {
  set $skip_cache 1;
}

# Don't cache uris containing the following segments
if ($request_uri ~* "(/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|/wp-(app|cron|login|register|mail).php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|index.php|wp-comments-popup.php|wp-links-opml.php|wp-locations.php|sitemap(_index)?.xml|[a-z0-9_-]+-sitemap([0-9]+)?.xml)") {
  set $skip_cache 1;
}

# Don't use the cache for logged in users or recent commenters
if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp-postpass|wordpress_no_cache|wordpress_logged_in") {
  set $skip_cache 1;
}
#end Caching

# WordPress single site rules.
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
   
#location /wp-content/themes/kdi-ecommerce/templates/ {
#    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$query_string;
#}


# Add trailing slash to */wp-admin requests.
rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

# Directives to send expires headers and turn off 404 error logging.
location ~* ^.+\.(eot|otf|woff|woff2|ttf|rss|atom|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
    access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
}

# Media: images, icons, video, audio send expires headers.
location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm)$ {
  expires 1M;
  access_log off;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}

# CSS and Javascript send expires headers.
location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
  expires 1y;
  access_log off;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
# HTML send expires headers.
location ~* \.(html)$ {
  expires 7d;
  access_log off;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}

# Browser caching of static assets.
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|pdf)$ {
  expires 7d;
  add_header Cache-Control "public, no-transform";
}

# Enable Gzip compression in NGNIX.
gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript image/svg+xml;

# Fast-CGI Cache configuration
location ~ \.php$ {
#location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$){
    #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;

    #if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
    #    return 404;
    #}

    include fastcgi-cache.conf;
    include fastcgi.conf; 
    #fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

    fastcgi_pass unix:run/php-fpm/www.sock;
    #enable cache
    add_header X-WP-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
    
    # Skip cache based on rules in snippets/fastcgi-cache.conf.
    fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
    fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;

    # Define memory zone for caching. Should match key_zone in fastcgi_cache_path above.
    fastcgi_cache restorebindemo;

    # Define caching time.
    fastcgi_cache_valid 60m;

    #PHP-FTP Buffers
    fastcgi_buffers 8 4k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 8k;

    #increase timeouts
    fastcgi_read_timeout 60s;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 60s;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 60s;
}
```

I have tried with all types of the try_files variations; i don't know if it's a location / block configuration.

Here is the fastcgi.conf:

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

As is said, if i put the php file that i need to execute with parameters in the / (same place as the wp-config.php file) it works, but no in subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

1. either to rewrite your path to the root, for example with own location for `/subfolder/subfolder2/` or using rewrite directive:

```
rewrite ^/subfolder/subfolder2/([^/]+\.php)$ $1 last;
```

2. or don't use `fastcgi_split_path_info` to split path, just try to supply the captured script name from location pattern, for instance add other location or rewrite your location `~ \.php$` like this:

```
- location ~ \.php$ {
+ location ~ ^/(?:subfolder/subfolder2/)?(?<script_name>[^/]+\.php)$ {
    ...
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $script_name;
  }
```